# TypeError: split() missing 1 required positional argument: 'split_size'

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, split

when I start my script I get this error:

```
TypeError: split() missing 1 required positional argument: 'split_size'
```

This is the full error message:

```
  File "c:/Users/supre/Documents/Python Programme/speech_reco._ai/speechrecognition/engine.py", line 111, in __call__
    trascript = " ".join(self.asr_results.split() + results.split())
TypeError: split() missing 1 required positional argument: 'split_size'
```

And this  is my source code:

```
import pyaudio
import threading
import time
import argparse
import wave
import torchaudio
import torch
import sys
import numpy as np
from neuralnet.dataset import get_featurizer
from decoder import DecodeGreedy, CTCBeamDecoder
from threading import Event


class Listener:

    def __init__(self, sample_rate=8000, record_seconds=2):
        self.chunk = 1024
        self.sample_rate = sample_rate
        self.record_seconds = record_seconds
        self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.stream = self.p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                        channels=1,
                        rate=self.sample_rate,
                        input=True,
                        output=True,
                        frames_per_buffer=self.chunk)

    def listen(self, queue):
        while True:
            data = self.stream.read(self.chunk , exception_on_overflow=False)
            queue.append(data)
            time.sleep(0.01)

    def run(self, queue):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.listen, args=(queue,), daemon=True)
        thread.start()
        print("\Speech Recognition engine is now listening... \n")


class SpeechRecognitionEngine:

    def __init__(self, model_file, ken_lm_file, context_length=10):
        self.listener = Listener(sample_rate=8000)
        self.model = torch.jit.load(model_file)
        self.model.eval().to('cpu')  #run on cpu
        self.featurizer = get_featurizer(8000)
        self.audio_q = list()
        self.hidden = (torch.zeros(1, 1, 1024), torch.zeros(1, 1, 1024))
        self.beam_results = ""
        self.out_args = None
        self.context_length = context_length * 50 # multiply by 50 because each 50 from output frame is 1 second
        self.start = False

    def save(self, waveforms, fname="audio_temp"):
        wf = wave.open(fname, "wb")
        wf.setnchannels(1)
        wf.setsampwidth(self.listener.p.get_sample_size(pyaudio.paInt16))
        wf.setframerate(8000)
        wf.writeframes(b"".join(waveforms))    
        wf.close()
        return fname

    def predict(self, audio):
        with torch.no_grad():
            fname = self.save(audio)
            waveform, _ = torchaudio.load(fname)  # don't normalize on train
            log_mel = self.featurizer(waveform).unsqueeze(1)
            out, self.hidden = self.model(log_mel, self.hidden)
            out = torch.nn.functional.softmax(out, dim=2)
            out = out.transpose(0, 1)
            self.out_args = out if self.out_args is None else torch.cat((self.out_args, out), dim=1)
            results = self.out_args          #self.beam_search()
            current_context_length = self.out_args.shape[1] / 50  # in seconds
            if self.out_args.shape[1] > self.context_length:
                self.out_args = None
            return results, current_context_length

    def inference_loop(self, action):
        while True:
            if len(self.audio_q) < 5:
                continue
            else:
                pred_q = self.audio_q.copy()
                self.audio_q.clear()
                action(self.predict(pred_q))
            time.sleep(0.05)

    def run(self, action):
        self.listener.run(self.audio_q)
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.inference_loop,
                                    args=(action), daemon=True)
        thread.start()


class DemoAction:

    def __init__(self):
        self.asr_results = ""
        self.current_beam = ""

    def __call__(self, x):
        results, current_context_length = x
        self.current_beam = results
        trascript = " ".join(self.asr_results.split() + results.split())
        print(trascript)
        if current_context_length > 10:
            self.asr_results = trascript

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="demoing the speech recognition engine in terminal.")
    parser.add_argument('--model_file', type=str, default='1.ptl', required=False,
                        help='optimized file to load. use optimize_graph.py')
    parser.add_argument('--ken_lm_file', type=str, default=None, required=False,
                        help='If you have an ngram lm use to decode')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    asr_engine = SpeechRecognitionEngine(args.model_file, args.ken_lm_file)
    action = DemoAction()

    asr_engine.run(action)
    threading.Event().wait()
```

Comment: Well the string function `split()` doesn't require any arguments, so is `asr_results` not a string?

Comment: Hello @Kevin , are those counted as strings ""?

Comment: Can you add this right before line 111 `print(type(asr_results))`

Comment: I think you are just missing an argument in your `action` instance. You've created an instance `action = DemoAction()` and your `__call__(self, x)` takes one argument, but the line in your code `asr_engine.run(action)`, `action` doesn't have any argument in it. It should be `asr_engine.run(action(SOME_ARG))`.

Comment: @syohey thank you very very much that fixed it for me:). Is it possible that you could help me please out with one more error which occours right after? If yes could you please add me on discord? Name: CodeForce1#8083

Comment: @Kevin could you add me on Discord too if you don't mind?